# How to adjacent a table in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in Mysql

```
SELECT z.virtuemart_product_id,z.product_name,d.product_price FROM x5lui_virtuemart_products x
  inner join x5lui_virtuemart_products_en_gb z on x.virtuemart_product_id=z.virtuemart_product_id
  inner join x5lui_virtuemart_product_prices d on d.virtuemart_product_id=z.virtuemart_product_id
where x.published=1;
```

And the result is

```
18, 'Product 1', 600.00000
19, 'Product 2', 1200.0000
20, 'Product 3', 1800.00000
```

But I need the result to be like this

```
'18', '19', '20'
'Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3'
600.00000 , 1200.0000, 1800.00000
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you, can use GROUP_CONCAT to get those results in the query result.  Here' s a simple Virtumart example that you'd have to adapt to use all those other tables in your question.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_id SEPARATOR '|') FROM jos_vm_product WHERE product_publish='Y'
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR '-') FROM jos_vm_product WHERE product_publish='Y'
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_price SEPARATOR '^') FROM jos_vm_product_price
```

OK I found it

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_id, '{ITEM}') FROM jos_vm_product WHERE product_publish='Y'
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name, '{ITEM}') FROM jos_vm_product WHERE product_publish='Y'
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_price, '{ITEM}') FROM jos_vm_product_price
```

Comment: so I can split on each row by Comma? I think your code will do my job

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, will 'explode' php function explode if there is a comma in the title? Can I add a custom delimiter that I am sure that will not explode the page? :P

Comment: with these results, you'll definately have to use explode to access the actual data, because the "columns" are comma-delimited strings, and yes, you can specify the delimniter - I'll adjust my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need this, but the only thing you can do there is to loop your query results:

```
foreach( $results as $result ){
   $array['ids'][]    = $result['virtuemart_product_id'];
   $array['names'][]  = $result['product_name'];
   $array['prices'][] = $result['product_price'];
}
```

Comment: Because the view is created in a way, that the loop has to print the prices line by line, so It would be easy for me if I had a data model like this. But if there is no other solution I will use your code to loop the model column by column each time.
The Business scope of the view is to compare prices side by side

Comment: Another solution would be to fix HTML structure, so you can print products data normally.

Comment: Yea probably, but there is a problem Huston. On each row I have a line separator that separates all rows, So I must print the first row and then move to the next :(.